# appcompat version and declaration issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

i try to migrate minSDK from 9 to 14 (that's newest play_services minimum). Target SDK is 17. When i change it manually in gradle and manifest after sync, a huge list of problems showing up. Most of them has something in common with appcompact.

```
E:\Android\Android\android studio projects\Sklepik\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
```

I think that these problems are because wrong version is in use (project works good few months ago), but i can't find place of declaration appcompact.
Right now i've got 2 dependiences in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
}
```

How to solve it?

---> Keyur, after change support version i have problem which looks like:
[image]

of course my internet connection is ok...

Comment: `...from 9 to 14 (that's newest play_services minimum)`...? Please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). The minimum supported platform is **10**.

Answer (score 0):

Add support v7 library

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:19.1.0'
```

Comment: Keyur can you look at the pic?

Comment: I think internet connection is slow or not available.

Comment: Right click -> app
click ->open module setting
click ->Dependencies (one popup window will their)
click -> top right plus symbol  (select library dependency)

now you will see pop up from which select support v7 library

Comment: I think you can install it from sdk/tool

Comment: no i didn't - i can't find it in manually add in dependencies and in sdk/tool

Comment: i've got android studio ver 1.5 maybe i should upgrade to newest version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138240/discussion-between-keyurthumar-and-bakusek).